Page auto-scrolls too far down when focused on input fields, creating black space and not scrolling back up
I am building a webpage using a flexbox layout and I am having some issues with scrolling for the mobile view when I am focused on an input field.
When I am focused on only input fields and scroll my page, it will scroll down to far creating a black space below the pages content. It will just be stuck there and the screen will not automatically scroll back up. Seems to be something to do with with the mobile screen handles a keyboard.
Here is the css components I am using
export const FullContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`

export const FullContainerBody = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`
export const FullContainerContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`
export const FullContainerHeader = styled.div`
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
`
export const FullContainerProgressBar = styled.div`
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
`
export const FullContainerSectionTitle = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px 30px 5px;
`
export const FullContainerValTitle = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px 5px;
`
export const FullContainerFormContent = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 0;
`
export const FullContainerFooter = styled.div`
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
`

And the component it is used in
return (
      <>
        <FullContainer>
          <FullContainerBody>
            <FullContainerContainer>
              <FullContainerHeader>
                <HeaderTest
                  user={user}
                  width={width}
                  ismobilescreen={ismobilescreen}
                />
              </FullContainerHeader>

              <FullContainerProgressBar>
                <CreatePracticeHeader
                  currentStep={currentStep}
                  ismobilescreen={ismobilescreen}
                  practice={practice}
                  currentFlow={currentFlow}
                  onSaveInFlow={onSaveInFlow}
                  nextEnabled={nextEnabled || allowSkipping}
                  inValuationMode={inValuationMode}
                  onValuationPage={onValuationPage}
                  isDueDiligence={isDueDiligence}
                />
              </FullContainerProgressBar>

              {onValuationPage ? (
                <FullContainerValTitle>
                  <CreatePracticeFormTitleContainer>
                    <CreatePracticeFormTitleText>
                      {formTitle}
                    </CreatePracticeFormTitleText>
                    {formSubtitle && (
                      <CreatePracticeFormSubtitleText
                        textColor={formSubtitleColor}
                      >
                        {formSubtitle}
                      </CreatePracticeFormSubtitleText>
                    )}
                  </CreatePracticeFormTitleContainer>
                </FullContainerValTitle>
              ) : (
                <FullContainerSectionTitle>
                  <CreatePracticeFormTitleContainer>
                    <CreatePracticeFormTitleText>
                      {formTitle}
                    </CreatePracticeFormTitleText>
                    {formSubtitle && (
                      <CreatePracticeFormSubtitleText
                        textColor={formSubtitleColor}
                      >
                        {formSubtitle}
                      </CreatePracticeFormSubtitleText>
                    )}
                  </CreatePracticeFormTitleContainer>
                </FullContainerSectionTitle>
              )}
              <FullContainerFormContent>
                {children ?? (
                  <CreatePracticeFormInputColumnContainerTest
                    ismobilescreen={ismobilescreen}
                    ref={divRef}
                  >
                    {ismobilescreen || !splitIntoMultipleColumns ? (
                      <CreatePracticeFormInputColumn splitScreen={false}>
                        <CreatePracticeFormInputContainer splitScreen={false}>
                          {formInputs?.map((i) => {
                            return i
                          })}
                        </CreatePracticeFormInputContainer>
                      </CreatePracticeFormInputColumn>
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        <CreatePracticeFormInputColumn splitScreen>
                          <CreatePracticeFormInputContainer splitScreen>
                            {firstHalfOfInputs?.map((i) => {
                              return i
                            })}
                          </CreatePracticeFormInputContainer>
                        </CreatePracticeFormInputColumn>
                        <CreatePracticeFormInputColumn splitScreen>
                          <CreatePracticeFormInputContainer splitScreen>
                            {secondHalfOfInputs?.map((i) => {
                              return i
                            })}
                          </CreatePracticeFormInputContainer>
                        </CreatePracticeFormInputColumn>
                      </>
                    )}
                  </CreatePracticeFormInputColumnContainerTest>
                )}
              </FullContainerFormContent>
              <FullContainerFooter>
                <CreatePracticeFlowNavigationPlaceholder
                  ref={navRef}
                  currentStep={currentStep}
                  practiceId={practice?.id}
                  nextEnabled={nextEnabled}
                  onClickBack={onClickBack}
                  onClickNext={onClickNext}
                  alternateNextButtonText={alternateNextButtonText}
                  allowSkipping={allowSkipping}
                  currentFlow={currentFlow}
                  completedWholeListingFlow={completedWholeListingFlow}
                  inValuationMode={inValuationMode}
                  skipButtonText={skipButtonText}
                  isDueDiligence={isDueDiligence}
                />
              </FullContainerFooter>
            </FullContainerContainer>
          </FullContainerBody>
        </FullContainer>
      </>
    )

Desired Behaviour
If the user does scroll down it should automatically scroll back up or not allow the user to be able to scroll further down while focused
